# How to join instead of union

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query with a union between 2 tables that works as expected but now I would like to override to join because I have a table with a field that can join between these two tables. Now when I write the join statement I was surprised that it get a table with a max value and apply the second table

let's have a look at code:

```
declare  @Users table (UserId int, UserName nvarchar(50))
insert into @Users(UserId,UserName) values 
(1,'Test users 1'),
(2,'Blah user')

declare  @Computers table (ComputerId int, UserId int, ComputerName nvarchar(50))
insert into @Computers (ComputerId, UserId,ComputerName)
values (3, 1, 'Test comp 3'),
(5, 2, 'blah 1'),
(6, 2, 'blah 1')

declare  @ComputersDeleted table (ComputerId int, UserId int, ComputerName nvarchar(50))
insert into @ComputersDeleted (ComputerId, UserId,ComputerName)
values (1, 1, 'Test comp 1'),
(2, 1, 'Test comp 2'),
(4, 2, 'blah')

-- excpected result
select * from @Computers where UserId = 1
union
select * from @ComputersDeleted where UserId = 1

select * from @Users u
left join @Computers c on c.UserId = u.UserId
left join @ComputersDeleted cd on cd.UserId = u.UserId
where u.UserId = 1
```

how to write a join as a union in this case?
I would like to get data like that

```
table 1, table 2 , table 3
data1    NULL      data3
data1    NULL      data3
data1    data2     NULL
```

instead of it works now, like apply

```
table 1, table 2 , table 3
data1    data2      data3
data1    data2      data3
```

Comment: I haven't the faintest idea what your question is.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: union and join perform very different operations. Imagine your tables are bricks in the wall that is your resultset - union puts one brick on top of the other (well, kinda) while join puts one brick next to the other.

Comment: u left join (select ... union ...) c on ...

Comment: Use `JOIN` for more columns and use `UNION` for more rows

Comment: The two "result sets" that you have posted aren't the results of any of the queries you have posted. You've taken the effort to create a test harness (and thank you), but these `data1 data2 whatever` examples aren't helpful. Show us what you're actually getting, what you actually want instead, and, if it's not really, really clear from those examples, what the logic is behind the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like :

```
select 
 UserId as Table1,
C.ComputersID as Table 2,
 null as Table3
 from @Users u
left join @Computers c on c.UserId = u.UserId
union
select 
 UserId as Table1,
 null as Table2,
cd.ComputersID as Table3
 from @Users u
left join @ComputersDeleted cd on cd.UserId = u.UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

With CTE

```
declare  @Users table (UserId int, UserName nvarchar(50))
insert into @Users(UserId,UserName) values 
(1,'Test users 1'),
(2,'Blah user')

declare  @Computers table (ComputerId int, UserId int, ComputerName nvarchar(50))
insert into @Computers (ComputerId, UserId,ComputerName)
values (3, 1, 'Test comp 3'),
(5, 2, 'blah 1'),
(6, 2, 'blah 1')

declare  @ComputersDeleted table (ComputerId int, UserId int, ComputerName nvarchar(50))
insert into @ComputersDeleted (ComputerId, UserId,ComputerName)
values (1, 1, 'Test comp 1'),
(2, 1, 'Test comp 2'),
(4, 2, 'blah')


--WITH CTE
;WITH table_union(ComputerId, UserId,ComputerName)
AS
(
select ComputerId, UserId,ComputerName   from @Computers
union ALL
select  ComputerId, UserId,ComputerName from @ComputersDeleted
)
select *
from @Users u
LEFT Outer join table_union ON table_union.UserId = u.UserId
where u.UserId = 1
```

You can also create a view which union the tables